# Extract a string from a CSV cell containing special characters in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I'm writing a Python program to extract specific values from **each cell in a .CSV file column** and then **make all the extracted values new columns**.

Sample column cell:(This is actually a small part, the real cell contains much more data)

```
AudioStreams":[{"JitterInterArrival":10,"JitterInterArrivalMax":24,"PacketLossRate":0.01353227,"PacketLossRateMax":0.09027778,"BurstDensity":null,"BurstDuration":null,"BurstGapDensity":null,"BurstGapDuration":null,"BandwidthEst":25245423,"RoundTrip":520,"RoundTripMax":11099,"PacketUtilization":2843,"RatioConcealedSamplesAvg":0.02746676,"ConcealedRatioMax":0.01598402,"PayloadDescription":"SIREN","AudioSampleRate":16000,"AudioFECUsed":true,"SendListenMOS":null,"OverallAvgNetworkMOS":3.487248,"DegradationAvg":0.2727518,"DegradationMax":0.2727518,"NetworkJitterAvg":253.0633,"NetworkJitterMax":1149.659,"JitterBufferSizeAvg":220,"JitterBufferSizeMax":1211,"PossibleDataMissing":false,"StreamDirection":"FROM-to-
```

One value I'm trying to extract is number `10` between the `"JitterInterArrival":` and `,"JitterInterArrivalMax"` . But since each cell contains relatively long strings and special characters around it(such as ""), `opener=re.escape(r"***")`and `closer=re.escape(r"***")` wouldn't work.

Does anyone know a better solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have a `json` string and wish to get values from its attributes. So, given

```
s = '''
{"AudioStreams":[{"JitterInterArrival":10,"JitterInterArrivalMax":24,"PacketLossRate":0.01353227,"PacketLossRateMax":0.09027778,"BurstDensity":null,
                  "BurstDuration":null,"BurstGapDensity":null,"BurstGapDuration":null,"BandwidthEst":25245423,"RoundTrip":520,"RoundTripMax":11099,"PacketUtilization":2843,"RatioConcealedSamplesAvg":0.02746676,"ConcealedRatioMax":0.01598402,"PayloadDescription":"SIREN","AudioSampleRate":16000,"AudioFECUsed":true,"SendListenMOS":null,"OverallAvgNetworkMOS":3.487248,"DegradationAvg":0.2727518,
                  "DegradationMax":0.2727518,"NetworkJitterAvg":253.0633,
                  "NetworkJitterMax":1149.659,"JitterBufferSizeAvg":220,"JitterBufferSizeMax":1211,
                  "PossibleDataMissing":false}]}
'''
```

You can do

```
import json
>>> data = json.loads(s)
>>> ji = data['AudioStreams'][0]['JitterInterArrival']
10
```

In a data frame scenario, if you have a column `col` of strings such as the above, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [s]})
```

You can use `transform` passing `json.loads` as argument

```
df.col.transform(json.loads)
```

to get a `Series` of dictionaries. Then, you can manipulate these dicts or just access the data as done above.

Comment: Ah I see. This seems correct. btw do you think `df['PacketLossRate'] = df.QoEReport.str.extract(r',\s*([^\.]*)\s*\.', expand=False)` wuld be more efficient? considering I need to extract entire column and make them all new ones. idk using json just seems a bit inconvient.

Comment: Well, since you have `json`-formatted objects, I don't see why not to use a widely-used and *tested* library to parse the data. Of course you are free to use regex and manually parse the objects, but I would recommend against doing it :)